# New wen appliction button is disabled for a farm user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

i am uisng SP 2013, but when i login to the central admin suing a farm user ,, the new web application button was disabled.. can anyone advice what is causing this ?/

Answer (score 0):

Why SharePoint 2013 Central Administration Ribbons Grayed Out?

1. Run Central Administation "as Administrator"
2. Run your browser as administrator and open Central Administration site inside it.

Hope that solves your problem.

http://answers.just4sharing.com/Questions/Index/118

Comment: i already did these..

Comment: That is fine. Hope your issue is solved. I too had this issue when I first installed SP 2013.